# Delete duplicate value and rearrange the data with out blank row

Tags: vba6, excel-2021

I am trying to clear duplicate value and rearrange the set of data starts from (A17 to C30)
To (EA1 to EC30.)
I cant add filter or delete the row. only copy & paste is the only option
I am having access to excel standard 2021.

I tried below code. having hard time to rearrange. and I dont want to delete any row and filter because i have a dashboard value filled in other cells.

```
Sub ClearRowValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the worksheet where your data is located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A with data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through rows from the bottom to the top
    For i = lastRow To 17 Step -1 ' Start from the second last row and move upwards
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            ' If the current Doc. No. is the same as the previous row, clear the current row
            ws.Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
            ws.Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
            ws.Cells(i, 3).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Seeking your help. please